# MySQL, Update query with inner joins fails silently

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have a MySQL query update with inner joins is not working while similar select query with inner joins works perfectly.

Working SELECT query

```
SELECT fa.tax_rate, efa.entity_id
FROM water_civicrmv2.civicrm_financial_account as fa
    INNER JOIN water_civicrmv2.civicrm_entity_financial_account efa ON efa.financial_account_id = fa.id 
    INNER JOIN water_civicrmv2.civicrm_option_value cov ON cov.value = efa.account_relationship
    INNER JOIN water_civicrmv2.civicrm_option_group cog ON cog.id = cov.option_group_id
    WHERE efa.entity_table = 'civicrm_financial_type'
    AND cov.name = 'Sales Tax Account is'
    AND cog.name = 'account_relationship'
    AND fa.is_active = 1
```

Failed UPDATE query

```
 UPDATE water_civicrmv2.civicrm_financial_account as fa
    INNER JOIN water_civicrmv2.civicrm_entity_financial_account efa ON efa.financial_account_id = fa.id 
    INNER JOIN water_civicrmv2.civicrm_option_value cov ON cov.value = efa.account_relationship
    INNER JOIN water_civicrmv2.civicrm_option_group cog ON cog.id = cov.option_group_id
    SET fa.tax_rate = '123123' 
    WHERE efa.entity_table = 'civicrm_financial_type'
    AND cov.name = 'Sales Tax Account is'
    AND cog.name = 'account_relationship'
    AND fa.is_active = 1
```

I really don't know why it fails silently as there is no syntax error, just nothing happens.

Comment: If that SELECT works, I'll eat my shorts.

Comment: @Strawberry I have updated the question, Please take a look again

Comment: If the interpreter doesn't throw any errors, then it must be a data issue. I recommend pulling manageable amounts of data into Excel, and then iteratively running queries and checking output to ensure that the join is executing as expected. I'm not a MySQL expert so it's possible that you have a syntax error in the UPDATE query.

Comment: Did you run the `SELECT` query in your MySQL console and then run `UPDATE` query in PHP? I say that because you have period qualifiers suggesting querying across databases. In PHP, you usually connect to one database whereas on a server console you have access to all databases.

Answer (score 1):

Change your update SQL so that the object of the UPDATE is only the single table water_civicrmv2.civicrm_financial_account:

```
 UPDATE water_civicrmv2.civicrm_financial_account as fa
    SET fa.tax_rate = '123123' 
    WHERE fa.id = 
          (SELECT fa.id
             FROM water_civicrmv2.civicrm_entity_financial_account efa
             INNER JOIN water_civicrmv2.civicrm_option_value cov ON cov.value = efa.account_relationship
             INNER JOIN water_civicrmv2.civicrm_option_group cog ON cog.id = cov.option_group_id
             WHERE efa.financial_account_id = fa.id 
               AND efa.entity_table = 'civicrm_financial_type'
               AND cov.name = 'Sales Tax Account is'
               AND cog.name = 'account_relationship'
               AND fa.is_active = 1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the result is still the same, and is not updating the field.

Comment: I see that you are updating fa.tax_rate using the string literal '123123'.  Is this field defined as a string type, or a numeric type?

Comment: Assuming that you are using the CiviCRM database, I think the problem is that the value you are specifying for fa.tax_rate is out of range.  That column is defined as decimal(10,8), which limits the values to the range -99.99999999 to 99.99999999.

Comment: I tried that and the issue is not that. I tried value 50.55 instead of 123123, still cannot update the field